# Disable text box on failure of 3 login attempts

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I have to disable the "Username" & "Password" text boxes when the user fails to provide correct credentials 3times. I should use the logic in JSP itself(using jQuery or javascript) or in the controller.

PS : I have to redirect to the login page only after failure. Just need to update the error message with "Your account has been disabled".

Below is the JSP: Login.jsp

```
        <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Login Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="Login_Servlet_Test" method="POST">
            Username <input type="text" name="uname"/><br>
            Password <input type="text" name="paswd"/><br>
            <input type="Submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Below is the Servlet: LoginServlet

```
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public void init() throws ServletException {
        //we can create DB connection resource here and set it to Servlet context
        if(getServletContext().getInitParameter("dbURL").equals("jdbc:mysql://localhost/mysql_db") &&
                getServletContext().getInitParameter("dbUser").equals("mysql_user") &&
                getServletContext().getInitParameter("dbUserPwd").equals("mysql_pwd"))
        getServletContext().setAttribute("DB_Success", "True");
        else throw new ServletException("DB Connection error");
    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        //get request parameters for userID and password
        String user = request.getParameter("user");
        String pwd = request.getParameter("pwd");

        //get servlet config init params
        String userID = getServletConfig().getInitParameter("user");
        String password = getServletConfig().getInitParameter("password");
        //logging example
        log("User="+user+"::password="+pwd);

        if(userID.equals(user) && password.equals(pwd)){
            response.sendRedirect("LoginSuccess.jsp");
        }else{
            RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("Login.jsp");
            PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
            out.println("<font color=red>Either user name or password is wrong.</font>");
            rd.include(request, response);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: @Archana you will need to use javascript for same and keep track of login attempts here..

Comment: locked users should be flagged in the database,
client side handling is easy to remove.
Add a login counter to the user model and update it after failure, successful login should reset the counter.
Another field should be a date representing the last time the user tried to login. if this field is greater than X hours you should reset the counter aswell

Comment: @navotgil good inputs..!!!

Comment: @Viraj Can you send a code snippet for the javascript logic you are mentioning here. It would be a great help. Thanks

Comment: Never do such things, users might have problems logging into your program. Locking user account might lead to unused accounts.

Comment: @RomanC In that case, user can recover the password using the "Forgot Password" link.

Comment: @Archna Sure, but only during registration process.

Comment: @Archna I have added in answers a example..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will to add a two columns in your Users table. One representing login count and another representing timestamp of last login attempt.
Mostly web sites allow user to attempt login after specific time after account was locked. So you may want to check time and also clear unsuccessful attempts if that specified time(e.g. 30 minutes since last login attempt) exceeds or user was able to login successfully.

```
PreparedStatement pstmt =  con.prepareStatement("select loginCount , loginAttemptDate from userstable where username=?");
pstmt.setString(1,username);//your username from login page
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
int loginAttempt=resultset.getint(1);
Date loginAttemptDate = new java.util.Date(resultSet.getTimestamp(2).get time());
request.setAttribute("loginCount",loginAttempt );
long diff= new Date().getTime() - loginAttemptDate.getTime();

if (diff < YOURTIMELIMITCONST && loginAttempt > 3 ){


RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("Login.jsp");
PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
out.println("<font color=red>Either user name or password is wrong.</font>");
        rd.include(request, response);
}else{
     //do your login check
}
```

and in jsp you do like using scriptlets

```
<%if((Integer)request.getAttribute("loginCount") > 3){%>
document.getElementById("usernamebox").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("passwordbox").disabled = true;
<%}%>
```

I assumed the ids of your input boxes in above code

Comment: @Archna have added some jdbc part just as example change it according to your database and table..